# MultipartFile says Null and search does not work

Tags: java, spring-boot

1.In the database or in the console,the fileName field shows NULL but the file or image is uploading in the directory.

2. search functionality is not working.when i type in the input and search it shows nothing but in the url i can see the desire search path example :http://localhost:8081/search?keyword=test here, the test is the keyword or a fileName i want to search.

```
[![File in Db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lv907.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lv907.png)
[![Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldf82.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldf82.png)
```

````
```
Entity
```
@Entity
@Table(name="User_Management")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String codicefiscale;
    private String documents;
    private String description;
    private String gender;
    private String city;
    private String fileName;
    @Column(length = 15)
    private long phone;

    // getter and setter
       ....
```
Repository
```
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{

    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE CONCAT(u.name, u.email) LIKE %:keyword%")
    List<User> search(String keyword);
    
}

```
Service Interface and implementation
```
public interface UserService {
    
    List<User> findAllUsers();
    User get(int id);
    User addUser(User user);
    User updateOrSave(User user);
    void delete(int id);
    User view(User user);
    
    List<User> listSearch(String keyword);

}

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepo userRepo) {
        super();
        this.userRepo = userRepo;
    }
    public UserRepo getUserRepo() {
        return userRepo;
    }
    public void setUserRepo(UserRepo userRepo) {
        this.userRepo = userRepo;
    }

    
                @Override
                public List<User> findAllUsers() {
                    
                    return this.userRepo.findAll();
                }
            
                @Override
                public User get(int id) {
                    
                    return this.userRepo.findById(id).get();
                }
            
                @Override
                public User addUser(User user) {
            
                    return this.userRepo.save(user);
                }
            
                @Override
                public User updateOrSave(User user) {
                    return this.userRepo.save(user);
                        
                }
            
                @Override
                public void delete(int id) {
                     this.userRepo.deleteById(id);;
                 
                }
            
                            
                //search functionality
                @Override
                public List<User> listSearch(String keyword) {
                    List<User> search = this.userRepo.search(keyword);
                    return search;
                    
//                   if (keyword != null) {
//                          return userRepo.search(keyword)
//                      }
//                      return userRepo.findAll();
                }
                @Override
                public User view(User user) {
                 return this.userRepo.save(user);
                }
            
    

}
```
Controller
```
@Controller
//@RequestMapping("/users")
public class MyController {
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyController.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    public MyController(UserService userService) {
        super();
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    public UserService getUserService() {
        return userService;
    }

    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    
    
    // Normal home page
        @GetMapping("/")
        public String Home()
        {
            return "home";
        }
    
    //   listing all the Users in a new Page.
        @GetMapping("/manage")
        public String ManageTheUsersList(Model m)
        {
            List<User> findAllUsers = this.userService.findAllUsers();
            m.addAttribute("ListUser", findAllUsers);
             m.addAttribute("title","User Management System");
            return "manageForm";
        }
        
        
        //  Show Add new User page
        @GetMapping("/addnewuser")
        public String addnewuser(Model m)
        {
            m.addAttribute("user", new User());
            m.addAttribute("title","User Management System");
            return "addForm";
        } 
        
        
        // save the Data from Add new User page
        @PostMapping("/saveaddeduser")
        public String addnewuser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user,@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile file,
                Model m, RedirectAttributes ra,HttpSession session,@RequestParam("gender") String gender)
        {
            String uploads = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/resources/static/files";
            System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));

        
     try {
         String originalFilename = file.getOriginalFilename();//ex:- abc.png
         Path Fullpath = Paths.get(uploads+File.separator+originalFilename);// /src/main/resource...abc.png
         Files.write(Fullpath,file.getBytes());
         m.addAttribute(originalFilename, Fullpath);
         m.addAttribute("message","uploaded files :" + Fullpath.toString());
         
         this.userService.addUser(user);
         ra.addFlashAttribute("message","User is successfully added !!");
            System.out.println(user);
        m.addAttribute("title","User Management System");
            
         }catch(Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
        return "redirect:/manage";
     }
     //@RequestMapping(path = {"/search"})
        @GetMapping("/search")
            public String Searching(@Param("keyword") String keyword,Model m) {
            
            // logger.info("Before Receiving search request for keyword:{}", keyword);
             
                List<User> listSearch = userService.listSearch(keyword);
                
              //  logger.info("Received search request for keyword:{}", listSearch);
                
                
                m.addAttribute("listSearch", listSearch);
                m.addAttribute("keyword", keyword);
                
                System.out.println(listSearch);
                System.out.println(keyword);
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
                return "manageForm"; 
            }
    }

```
Html
```
<form th:action="@{/saveaddeduser}" method="post" th:object="${user}" class="mt-2"
                enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- Files-->
    <div class="custom-file mb-3">
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="files" aria-label="file example"
    placeholder="Carta d'Identita" >
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Example invalid form file feedback</div>
    </div>
...
```
pom.xml
```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>Employee_management</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Employee_management</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
````